# DNS Loop scan for IP addresses in range

Tags: bash, powershell, ubuntu, dns, scanning

I would like to scan for dns from ip address 192.168.1.1 through 192.168.1.100. My command is below for a DNS loop scan which will display the domain name pointer, etc.

my command below

`for ip in $(seq 1 100); do host 192.168.1.$ip; done | column -t`

The problem I'm having is it is changing the first octet "192" from 1 to 100 opposed to the last octet "1-100".

Is there a way to edit my command to do that?

Comment: `192.168.xxx.xxx` is a Class C private address and you should not change `192` to other value.

Comment: I know i want to know how to fix it so 192 remains but 192.168.1."x", that "x" value changes from 1 to 100 @tshiono

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. But I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you running it on `bash`?

Comment: Just call me curious., Why is this tagged PowerShell? It's not PowerShell code or PowerShell code issue.

Answer (score 1):

The command `host 192.168.1.x`is trying to lookup `PTR` record for the host`x.168.192.in-addr.arpa` (where `x = 1..100` in your case) and it will fail with the result `3(NXDOMAIN)` for each `x` unless you are running name server for the zone `168.192.in-addr.arpa`.

Your script will scan your network only if you run private DNS server for this domain and the computer that runs this script has this private nameserver in the first line of `/etc/resolve.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell way of doing this, if PowerShell is what you are after, is something like this...

Localhost

```
Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | 
ForEach-Object {Resolve-DnsName $PSitem.IPAddress}
```

Or via ADDS

```
(Get-ADComputer -Identity '*').Name | 
ForEach {Resolve-DnsName -Name $PSItem}
```

See the help files for more details

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Resolve-Dns).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Resolve-Dns).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Resolve-Dns -Examples
Get-help -Name Resolve-Dns -Full
Get-help -Name Resolve-Dns -Online

Find-Module -Name '*dns*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize


Get-Command -Name '*dns*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```